# safari - different calculation div percent

Tags: html, css, safari, height

i have 2 divs like a column. Now the Problem is, the right div is higher than the left div. why? i want to work with percent.

I have only this Problem in safari

I hope somebody can help me. I don't understand the Problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "de">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "./css/smartphone/480.css" media = "screen and (min-device-width: 1px) and (max-device-width: 480px)">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "./css/smartphone/1024.css" media = "screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "./css/desktop/desktop.css" media = "screen and (min-device-width: 1025px)">

    </head>
    <body>
                <div id = "links">
                    <div style = "height:20%; background-color:#ECECEC;">
                    </div>
                    <div style = "height: 15%; background-color:#2DAB66;">
                    </div>
                    <div style = "height: 16%; background-color:#ECECEC;">
                    </div>
                    <div style = "height: 15%; background-color:#1E788B;">
                    </div>
                    <div style = "height: 34%; background-color:#ECECEC;">
                    </div>  
                </div>

                <div id = "mitte" >

                </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    /*margin-top: 1%;
    background-color: white;
    width: auto;
    height: 95%;
    min-height: 95%;*/
    background-color: #3C3C3B;
}


#links {
    width:13%;

    min-height:95%;
    height: auto;
    height: 95%;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    left: 12.1%;
}

#mitte {
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    max-height:95.0%;
    height: auto;
    height: 95.0%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with the browser's default styling. Try adding a [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css) file before your custom styles and see if that fixes it.

Also, please be clearer with what you mean by "the middle div"

Comment: Yes, I see at least 30 `div`s

Comment: check this site to see the Problem http://www.benwillgruber.com/neueSeite/ try it with Safari and ie. you can see the different. the middle div is higher in safari